# Leaflet + Google in Angular 2 - wrong order of tiles

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, leaflet

I am working with Leaflet and Google in Angular 2 and have a problem - can't get the Tilemill tiles to render properly - they appear in some strange order.

Here is what I get:
[image]

So, not all parts are even there and they are mixed now

Here is my code

map.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from "leaflet";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 10,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
  });
  constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
  let map = L.map("map", {
    center: [48.13, 11.57],
    zoom: 15,
    zoomControl: true,
    maxZoom: 10
  }).addLayer(this.googleStreets);
   map.invalidateSize();
  L.control.scale().addTo(map);
}}
```

Here HTML

```
<p>Map</p>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Here is CSS

```
#map {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need this stylesheet in your index.html

https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css